# isMovingFromParent property not set/false when search bar is active

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

xCode 10.2.1, iOS 12.1

I'm using a tableView with a searchbar. Everything is working fine, except a strange behavior when the navigationBar is visible during a search.

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

When I leave the default setting (`hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true`) the back button and title disappears, if I enter something into the searchbar. Then I have to press the search bar's cancel button and afterwards the back button. The Method `viewWillDisappear()` gets called and `isMovingFromParent` is set to `true`.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if isMovingFromParent {
        ...
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, I just don't like this behavior, to have to tap on cancel and on the back button.
I would like to enter a search string, see my results in my tableview, maybe select some of them and without tapping on the search bar's cancel button, just tap on the back button.
Therefore I set `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false` and tried it.

But when doing this `isMovingFromParent` is suddenly false.
Can someone please explain me why this happens, at least for me it makes no sense.